# Vigorous secondary fermentation after fruit addition

Tags: secondary-fermentation, fruit

I've racked my beer to a secondary fermentor and added about two liters of watermelon juice.  I placed the airlock on as I always do during secondary fermentation but the fruit sugar is causing a vigorous fermentation.  The airlock was filled with gunk within an hour.

Should I leave the airlock off until the fermentation slows down a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a very quick response - was there still a lot of yeast in suspension?

Keep that fermention covered any way you can - fruit flies are going to lose their minds over this stuff. I suggest a blowoff tube going into some sanitizer.